# Google Analytics blocked by navigator

Tags: angular, heroku, google-analytics, jhipster

I deployed a jhipster/angular app to heroku and I want to add Google Analytics but the script is blocked by the browser CSP.

I tried to bundle the script directly in the app but with same result

Any idea why? I don't want to change the security conf

**Edit**

For people facing same issue this worked for me

SecurityConfiguration class :

```
.contentSecurityPolicy("default-src 'self' www.google-analytics.com www.googletagmanager.com; frame-src 'self' data:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://storage.googleapis.com www.google-analytics.com www.googletagmanager.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' www.google-analytics.com www.googletagmanager.com data:; font-src 'self' data:")
```

and in the index.html

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXX"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'UA-XXXX');
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is blocked by the [content security policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy). By default the CSP is quite strict in jhipster. You can modify it in `SecurityConfiguration`. This is the [template](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/149aabde505bbd64e1a1f7a70ac503ef8b8dc3fc/generators/server/templates/src/main/java/package/config/SecurityConfiguration.java.ejs#L244) provided by default.

For testing you could also remove the CSP statement completely and analytics should load.

Comment: The thing is that on localhost everything works fine but on heroku  the script is blocked.

Comment: Clicking on the blocked notice in your dev tools should show you what part is responsible for blocking. Is the analytics code also on localhost trying to track something?

Comment: It has been fixed in the current master and will be part of the upcoming 7 beta version. https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/12687